# Bootstrap cards under each other

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Now i have this:

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">

{{#each stories}}

  <div class="col">
    <div class="card shadow-sm">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ image }}">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">{{ description }}</p>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <a href="story/{{_id}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Читать</a>
          <small class="text-muted">author</small>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{{/each}}

</div>
```

And it looks like:
[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Kml.png)

I want the cards to be under each other: [Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws0LK.png)

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox (or similair)?

Answer (score 0):

> if you wanna put every card under each other you should put w-100 to each of cards or change your code like this :

```
 <div class="row g-4">

{{#each stories}}

  <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
    <div class="card shadow-sm">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ image }}">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">{{ description }}</p>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <a href="story/{{_id}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Читать</a>
          <small class="text-muted">author</small>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{{/each}}

</div>
```